# Power bi Visual behaving odd for text box and icon

Tags: powerbi

I am designing a Power bi Report where i need format my icon and textbox something like below mention image.

[image]

But when i am trying to achieve this only icon is visible but the text box is coming as grey as below mentioned image.

[image]

would anyone please help me to achieve my goal. can share additional details if anyone required.

Comment: did you check font?

Comment: Can you be specific what do i need to check in font.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you added the Text box via **Home > Text box**.

Select the text in the Text Box, then click the dropdown by the A in the toolbar to set the color of the font.

[image: Font settings]

The background color is in the Formatting Pane. Here's what it looks like with the new Formatting Pane as of the November 2021 release:

[image]